# Using nodejs to display SQLServer Query result on a html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Newbie to nodejs I have the server set up and I have the query running and displaying as json. However I would like this json information to be displayed in a table in the html. I will include some code below.

```
//Connection String parameters
```

sql.connect(sqlConfig, function (req, res) {

```
app.get("/reportStock", (req, res) => {
  var request = new sql.Request();
  request.query("select * from Products", function (err, resu) {
    res.json(resu.recordset);
    console.log(resu)

    var someData = JSON.stringify(res.recordsets);
    console.log(someData);
    res.render(__dirname + "/views/northwind.html", {
      fullList: someData
    });
  });
 });
}); // End of SQL Connect Statement
```

So if i navigate to localhost:8100/reportStock   I get this:

```
[{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Chai","SupplierID":1,"CategoryID":1,"QuantityPerUnit":"10 boxes x 20 
bags","UnitPrice":29700,"UnitsInStock":39,"UnitsOnOrder":0,"ReorderLevel":10,"Discontinued":false},
```

HTML:

```
 <h1> Products</h1>
        <h1>Pick one here please</h1>
        <h2> <%- fullList[0].ProductID %> </h2>
        <h2> <%- fullList[1].ProductName %> </h2>
        <div id='d1'></div>


<script>
var theFullList = <%-fullList%>;

for (var i=0;i<995;i++) {

    document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML += theFullList[i].ProductID + " - "
    document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML += theFullList[i].ProductName + "<br>"
}
</script>
```

Could anyone share some html/javascript on how I can get that Json result from the /reportStock into one of my regular html pages and display it as a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data form your url using javascript, ajax and display as table.

Here I'm using JQuery only for append data(you can use plain javascript also)

```
<html>
    //... meta tags goes here
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
       (async () => { // if you want to use await your immediate parent function should be async
          let response = await fetch('http://<your domain>//reportStock'); // Fetch data
          let data = await response.json(); // Convert to JSON
          data.forEach(_d => { // Loop through data and append to table, Here I'm just using ProductID for reference. 
             let tr = '';
             tr += `<td> ${_d.ProductID} </td>`
             $('#data-table').append(tr);
          });
       }
    </script>
    <body>
        <table id="data-table">
           <th> Headers goes here </th>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied this code in but it only displays the headers. Am I supposed to customise this code somehow?

Comment: Obviously I put the correct into the fetch, but I didnt change anything else

Comment: Put console to check response console.log(response), console.log(data). So that we can find is there any data received from server? And use try catch to find is there any exception occurred?

Comment: All the data is working and showing in the log, its the javascript/html where its not showing up